# Trying to run PHP file with parameters using MFC

Tags: url, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying this MFC code:

```
CString strURL = _T("https://www.website-to-use.co.uk/file.php?");
strURL.AppendFormat(_T("mwblang=%d"), theApp.GetForeignLanguageGroupCachedLanguageID());
strURL.AppendFormat(_T("&guilang=%d"), theApp.GetProgramLanguage());
strURL.AppendFormat(_T("&flg=%d"), theApp.GetForeignLanguageGroupMenuID() != ID_OPTIONS_GROUP_LANGUAGE_NONE);

InternetGoOnline((LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)strURL, GetSafeHwnd(), 0);
```

It is not working. If I go to the same link using a browser (correct details ofcourse) then it updates my database. But trying to run this from my MFC application, nothing happens

Comment: Have you tried using `strURL.operator LPCTSTR()` or `strURL.GetString()` in place of the double cast? (Not sure if you even need to cast out the `const` part.) Can't see why that would make a difference, though - just a suggestion.

Comment: @AdrianMole I have taken onboard your comments. Pleasesee my answer. That works. I am open to improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
CString strURL = _T("https://website-to-use.co.uk/file.php?");
strURL.AppendFormat(_T("mwblang=%d"), theApp.GetForeignLanguageGroupCachedLanguageID());
strURL.AppendFormat(_T("&guilang=%d"), theApp.GetProgramLanguage());
strURL.AppendFormat(_T("&flg=%d"), theApp.GetForeignLanguageGroupMenuID() != ID_OPTIONS_GROUP_LANGUAGE_NONE);

if (InternetGoOnline(strURL.GetString(), GetSafeHwnd(), 0))
{
    CInternetSession    iSession;
    CHttpFile* pWebFile = nullptr;

    pWebFile = (CHttpFile*)iSession.OpenURL(strURL, 1,
        INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE | INTERNET_FLAG_TRANSFER_BINARY | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD);

    if (pWebFile != nullptr)
    {

        pWebFile->Close();
        delete pWebFile;
    }
    iSession.Close();
}
```